# Facebook Graph API friends birthdays

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, facebook-graph-api

I searched a lot, I didn't succeeded in getting the friends birthday

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me" andDelegate:self];
```

what should I write instead of me to get the friends birthdays.
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer & it is as follows:

```
NSMutableDictionary * params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                @"select uid,name,birthday_date from user where uid in (select uid2 from friend where uid1=me())", @"query",
                                nil];
[[StaticFacebook getFacebook] requestWithMethodName: @"fql.query" 
                       andParams: params
                   andHttpMethod: @"POST" 
                     andDelegate: self];
```

Comment: Congrats ! Your answer helped me dude ! & which was helpful to help my friend & he was helping to some other person :D :P

Answer (score 3):

Try with below:

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends" 
                         andParams:[ NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"picture,id,name,link,gender,last_name,first_name",@"fields",nil]
                       andDelegate:self];
```

Let me know in case of query/difficulty.

Sometimes, 
Birthday value will be like "null" or only "month & date" or the "full date". So you have to check it manually.

I have one requirement in which I have to display only Month & Date.

You can check it from below function:

```
+(NSString *)getShortDate:(NSString *)pstrDate{
    NSArray *arrayDateData = [pstrDate componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
    NSString *strShortDate = @"";
    if([arrayDateData count]>=2){
        strShortDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [arrayDateData objectAtIndex:0], [arrayDateData objectAtIndex:1]];
    }
    return strShortDate;
}
```

Here, "pstrDate" date value is Facebook birthday date value.

I hope it will be helpful to you.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Get friends_birthday using graph api:

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends?fields=id,name,gender,picture,birthday" andDelegate:self];
```

and add permissions like this:

```
_permissions = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                     @"read_friendlists",@"publish_stream ,user_checkins", 
                     @"friends_checkins", @"publish_checkins",@"email", nil] 
                 retain];
```