# Fetching birthday field of Facebook friend in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook-graph-api

I want to fetch birthday of Facebook friends.I am using graph api, i know that i have to use `me/friends` of graph API. But the problem is that whenever i pass url like

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?[ACCESS TOKEN]&fields=id,name,picture,gender,birthday
```

It gives data which contain fields like name,id,picture and gender only but its not showing birthday field.
Any idea, how to fetch the desired result.

Comment: go through this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8645911/facebook-graph-api-friends-birthdays

Comment: i have gone through link,tried both case - first one was displaying all the fields except birthday field nd in 2nd case, birthday field was coming null.

Comment: Birthday field coming back as null coul also me that the friends have not given permission for friend’s apps to have access to that data …

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take extended permission `friends_birthday`

Then the above query works.

FYI:
[Extended permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/)
[User Object - check birthday field](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/)

Comment: I have checked this read two times but even then m not getting why my birthday field is coming null.

Answer (score 1):

You can get `friends_birthday` using the graph API:

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends?fields=id,name,gender,picture,birthday" andDelegate:self];
```

and add permissions like this:

```
_permissions = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"read_friendlists",@"publish_stream ,user_checkins", 
             @"friends_checkins", @"publish_checkins",@"email", nil] retain];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Now Facebook give permission for user_birthday only if you submit your app in developer.facebook.com for review. If Facebook give permission to your app after successfull review then you will find user_birthday live.
```

Then use NSString *urlString = [NSString
                           stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=%@&fields=email,name,gender,picture,birthday,relationship_status",
                           token.tokenString];

Answer (score -1):

me/friends?fields=id,name,picture,birthday

Try that in graph api explorer, to test your permissions.

Works fine for me.

Ps. Don't forget to select friends_birthday and generate your access key.

Comment: This answer is only saying that you tried what the asker did with success, but does not provide a solution.